# Unable to call a method that is declared in one class from another singleton class

Tags: javascript, angular

As the title says I'm trying to access a method that is declared in one class (Post) from another class (Comments) which is following a singleton pattern. Post class is a service class which has some methods to make API calls. So I need to have access to them from inside Comments class so that I can make API calls.

This is how a simplied version of Post class looks like right now:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class PostService extends AnotherService {

  constructor( auth: AuthService, http: HttpClient ) {
    super('string', auth, http);
  }

  getPost( id: string ) {
    return this.http.get(`posts/${id}`);
  }

}
```

This is how the Comments class look like:

```
class Comments {

    private postService: PostService;
    private static instance;
 
    private constructor() {}

    static createInstance() {
        if ( !Comments.instance ) {
            Comments.instance = new Comments();
        }
        return Comments.instance;
    }

    getComments( id ) {

        // these does not even run
        this.postService.getPost( id )
            .then( post => {
                 console.log( post );
            })
            .catch( error => {
                 console.log( error );
            }); 

    }

}
```

How can I go about accessing it?

=========UPDATE=======

Creating an instance of Comment class in another class called ClassC.

```
const instance - Comments.createInstance();
instance.getComments( id );
```

Comment: Services are singleton. Why aren't you making CommentsService instead of a Comments class?

Comment: because I only need to create one instance of it which is being created in another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to send two http request in parallel then get their values You should use combineLatest rxjs operator.
Your post service will be like this:

```
getPost(id: string) {
  $postDataHttpRequest = this.http.get(`posts/${id}`);
  $commentsDataHttpRequest = this.http.get(`posts/${id}/comments`);
  return combineLatest($postDataHttpRequest, $commentsDataHttpRequest)
}
```

///

This is how the Comments class look like:

```
  private constructor(private postService: PostService) {

  }
      getComments() {
            this.postService.getPost( '1' )
              .subscribe( (posts,comments) => {
                console.log(posts);
                console.log(comments);
              },(error)=>{console.log(error)})
             
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a new service to save your comment object data
let say We have a service named SharedDataService.

```
private _comments: Array<any> =[];// or array<IComment> (a defined interface from your part)
class SharedDataService(){}
get comments():Array<any>{
return this._comments}
set comments(value:Array<any>){
this._comments = value;

}

}
```

You should init PostService on your Comments Constructor

```
    private constructor(private postService: PostService,private sharedDataService :SharedDataService) {

}

    getComments() {

        // these does not even run
        this.postService.getPost( '1' )
            .then( post => {
this.sharedDataService.comments = post // if You get an array of comments here
                 console.log( post );
console.log(this.comments)// getter function its new value has been set
            })
            .catch( error => {
                 console.log( error );
            }); 

get comments(){

this.sharedDataService.comments

}

    }
```

Comment: Ummm shows an underline under postService that says Duplicate Identfier. Also new Comments() is underlined which says expected 1 argument

Comment: remove declared     private postService: PostService;

Comment: Now only new Comments() is underlined. It expects 1 argument.

Comment: your class structure not fine.You should use a SharedDataService to share your comment object after initialisation.

Comment: Post has been edited  to fix your issue :)

Comment: Hey. check the op. I have updated the post with how an instance is being created. I'm checking your updated answer

Comment: is all comments retrieved from post request or You wan to have addition get request for comment?

Comment: yes only from post service. I'll fetch the post with the id passed in getComments.

Comment: I just need ```this.postService.getPost``` to fire. Please note that the app I'm working on is totally different. I tried to simplify as far as I could to get a solution.

Comment: ok I will change code to fix your problem

Comment: Okay ummm your new SharedDataService is not needed in this case I guess as I cant even fire ```this.postService.getPost``` in the first place. Without firing it, I wont have access to comments.

Comment: Ok ..I'm happy to fixing your issue ^^

Comment: Hey you're still looking for a fix right?

Comment: check solution on a new post